# android listview load previous posts button at the top

Tags: android, json, listview, chat

I have a messaging application. I can get messages and list from mysql database via json. When i get messages (for example last 10 messages and newer is at the bottom) first record is shown at the top, so user have to scroll down to see last message. I want to focus to last message and when user scrolls to top, I want to put there a Load Previous Messages button. I found Load More buttoni but its at the bottom of page. How can I do that? 
My codes are these:

```
 // Hashmap for ListView
    categoryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // get listview
     ListView lv = getListView();
     Button btnLoadMore = new Button(this);
     btnLoadMore.setText("Load older messages");

    FrameLayout footerLayout = (FrameLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listfooter,null);
    lv.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);
```

Comment: Simply change `addFooterView()` with `addHeaderView()` might help.

Comment: thanks for answer. Well how can I focus to bottom and last message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in comments, simply change `addFooterView()` to [`addHeaderView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) method which give you the *Load More* at the top of the list. This method use three parameters (at least one: **View** from [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29)) which are:

- **View v:** the *Load More* view to add at the top
- **Object data:** data associated to the view
- **boolean isSelectable:** value to make the view selectable or not

Using these three params instead of only the view may allow you to prevent the color state on it by using `android:listSelector` attribute. Indeed, sometimes you want to prevent a background state on a header/footer view. That being says, the method might be:

```
lv.addHeaderView(headerLayout, null, false); // this isn't clickable now
```

<sup>*Note: now, you can call the view variable `headerLayout` instead of `footerLayout`* ;)</sup>

As I understand your requirements, `HeaderView` should have the *Load More* `Button` into it, to avoid to create it dynamically, as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center" >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Load More"
        android:onClick="loadMoreDatas" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, you have the right Button at the top of your list and you can add a method to handle the click event into the `Activity` (refer to `android:onClick` attribute) as:

```
public void loadMoreDatas(View v) {
    // load more messages
}
```

Finally, to focus to a specific item, in your case the last item in the list (at the bottom), you should use `setSelection(int position)` which **go to the index selected** in its parameter. Then, after setting the `Adapter`, call this on the `ListView` as:

```
// set the adapter
setListAdapter(adapter);
// go to selection (last item)
lv.setSelection(adapter.getCount() - 1);
```

The `getCount()` method use (*normally*) your `ArrayList` size. Then, you have to prevent an [IndexOutBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) because your array begins with position `0` and not `1`. So, the last position is *"All Items less First Position (0)"*.

However, the perfect method **to begin at the bottom of the list** is [`setStackFromBottom()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setStackFromBottom%28boolean%29):

> When stack from bottom is set to true, the list fills its content starting from the bottom of the view.

Then, it might be better to have:

```
// start from bottom
lv.setStackFromBottom(true);
```

This should do the trick and I hope this will be usefull.

Comment: Great Solutions, well how can i say "add this messages to top of listview" after clicking Load Older Messages Button?

Comment: With `add` method, you can set an index at first parameter @BilalTürk. So basically, do `categoryList.add(0, newData);` and make a `loop` to add new datas always at the top: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5903875/2668136) is exactly what you are looking for (except Runnable).