# ListView with recent objects at top

Tags: android, listview, sorting, adapter

I am populating ListView with an adapter as:

```
ListView lv;
FilterAdapter adapter=new FilterAdapter(Brand,Model,Price,Id);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here FilterAdapter is another adapter class made by me.
When I am adding, the last added object is going at the bottom of the listview, I want it to come on top and the order of items in listview to be recently added-last added.
How can i achieve this, do i have to make changes in FilterAdapter class (getView() method)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903597/add-new-items-to-top-of-list-view-on-android

Comment: Brand,Model,Price,Id Sort this abject from when u add one than added first

Comment: Please make list and then sort by what you want. then set adapter in listview.

Comment: post code if u not understnad.......

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar code is quite big, if  want any selcted section, i can post

Comment: @KrunalIndrodiya i do have a lists, whick i am populating from database, i dont know how to sort a list after adding..

Comment: @Slash Please follow this link http://java2novice.com/java-collections-and-util/arraylist/sort-comparator/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this, by adding these tags into your XML file (the one you have your `ListView`.

```
android:stackFromBottom="true"
android:transcriptMode="normal"
```

hope it helps