# Add new items on top of list view

Tags: android, listview

Because android automatically moves new items to the bottom of list view I want that to be reversed. In any case my condition is met, I want to add new items on top of list view.
I have seen this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903597/add-new-items-to-top-of-list-view-on-android) but I don't know how to add that to my code, here it is:

```
if(condition){
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, R.layout.list_b_text, R.id.list_content, ArrayofName);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: try to reverse **ArrayofName** before adding it into the Adapter.

Comment: Give me a moment, let me check it

Comment: use `stack` instead of `list`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add new items to top of list view on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903597/add-new-items-to-top-of-list-view-on-android)

Comment: @Akbar  It works by reversing, thank you

Comment: @We'reAllMadHere Its not Android who adds element to bottom of list. Android simply displays arraylist content. So you need to maintain your list. As others are suggesting, add element in top of arraylist and call `adapter.setNotifyDataSetChanged`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simply add every item at *position 0* of your `ArrayList` so when you call `listView.notifyDataSetChanged();` it will show latest items on top.

```
for (Object obj : objectList) {
    ArrayofName.add (0, obj); // this adds new items at top of ArrayList
}
```

`objectList` is basically an `ArrayList` or `List` of `Object` or `String` (whatever is your case). If you want to add items one by one, remove for loop. This loop actually iterates every item of `objectList` and adds it in your `ArrayList` at top position.

Comment: I have found my answer but since you proposed your way which I think is also right, I want to ask what exactly is  `(Object obj : objectList)`

Comment: objectList is basically an ArrayList or List of Object or String (whatever is your case). If you want to add items one by one, remove for loop. This loop actually iterates every item of objectList and adds it in your ArrayList at top position.

Comment: Thanks!, Since your answer works and I can't accept a comment as the right one I'll go ahead and accept yours