# How to make new inserted rows become on top of ListView (Android Studio)

Tags: android, xml, sorting, listview

The usual thing when I insert a new row into a ListView it is added at the bottom of the ListView by default. Can I make it upside down? I want the new added rows be on top, or I may say I want the ListView in descending flow sorted by time.
Is there a way to implement that from ListView settings? or it is related to the List connected with the ListView?
I searched about it and all I could find is "stackFromBottom" which makes the view of ListView scroll down and start showing from the bottom, and it is different from what I want.

Comment: Try this, Collections.reverse();  might work for you.

Comment: are you using recyclerview?

Comment: Reverse your array before setting to adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add row to top using add function with index.

example :

items.add(0, obj)

inside adapter you have item list that you add the row to top(index 0) and call

notifyiteminserted or notifydatasetchanged

probably duplicated 
[Add new items to top of list view on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903597/add-new-items-to-top-of-list-view-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in several way

1.You can use `Collections` Feature. After add item in your List then call  `Collections.reverse()` then update your `ListView`

2.You can set your List to `add(0,value)` 0 no position then update your `ListView`